Is it safe to not close a StreamController.broadcast() in a shared service?
I have a service that uses a StreamController.broadcast() and is shared among multiple BLoCs. Since multiple BLoCs/widgets may be using the stream at the same time, I can’t close the StreamController when a widget is disposed.
class SharedService {

  StreamController<MyEvent> _controller = StreamController<MyEvent>.broadcast();
  
  Stream<MyEvent> get events => _controller.stream;

  // ...
}

The documentation says a broadcast stream does not buffer events, so
is it safe to leave the broadcast StreamController open, or will it cause memory leaks?

there's no doubt that closing stream is a better option, just check if there are any listeners and close whenever no one is listening, you can schedule a timer function to periodically check if there's any listeners and close both the stream and this timer.

Leaving a StreamController.broadcast() open will not directly cause memory leaks if it’s handled correctly, but it can lead to problems if not properly handled.
It is safe to leave the StreamController.broadcast() open as long as:

You clean up listeners properly.
The SharedService is managed with an appropriate lifecycle.

